# Using webpack-dev-server to serve HTML pages outside of project directory

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

Is there a way to use webpack-dev-server (Webpack 5) just to serve HTML files (without bundling any JavaScript)?

Specifically, I need the following two things:

1. Serving HTML files with live reloading on change.
2. Ability to serve HTML files that is located outside of my project directory. Path to the file is known before the webpack-dev-server is created.

Webpack seems to only work well for bundling and serving JavaScript files, but I'm having trouble setting it up for this simple use case.

(I know there are alternatives like Vite, but my project already has Webpack set up. If possible I'd like to avoid adding/switching to another library.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My hacky solution is to programmatically write to a JS file that injects HTML to `index.html`, and then rewrite that JS file every time changes are made to my HTML file.

Sample code:

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");

// assuming fileContent is the content of my HTML file
root.innerHTML = "${fileContent.trim()}";
```

The JS file is then passed to webpack, which generates a "bundle.js" in my output directory.

Here is my `index.html` file:

```html
// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```